# The state of usestate is not updated for all error for the forms

Tags: reactjs

How can I update the state for all of the errors?

for example, I have to validate the fields name and last name:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const { name, lastName } = fields
    let existError = false

    if (!verify(name)) {
      existError = true
      setError({ ...error, ['name']: 'name is bad' })
    }

    if (!verify(lastName)) {
      existError = true
      setError({ ...error, ['lastName']: 'lastname is bad' })

    }

    if (!existError) {
     ...
    }
  }
  console.log('ERROR', error)
```

I can only see this error

ERROR `{lastName: 'lastname is bad'}`
i am waiting this result:

```
{name: 'name is bad', lastName: 'lastname is bad'}
```

Comment: can you provide some certification on what exactly you are doing and please provide some more code to help us to understand your problem

Comment: @Athena i updated my question, i am waitng this result: {name: 'name is bad', lastName: 'lastname is bad'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `error` within your `handleSubmit` function won't update until the next render, so when you set lastName:

```
setError({ ...error, ['lastName']: 'lastname is bad' })
```

`error` still doesn't have the `name` property and you end up overwriting the name update with the lastName update.

You're effectively doing this:

```js
const error = {
  foo: 123
}

let state = {
  ...error,
  name: 'name is bad'
}

console.log(state); // { foo: 123, name: 'name is bad' }

state = {
 ...error, // still doesn't contain 'name'
 lastName: 'last name is bad'
}

console.log(state); // { foo: 123, lastName: 'last name is bad' }
```

You could avoid this by collecting your errors in a separate object and doing a single state update that includes all of them.

```js
let errors = {};

if(!verify(name)) {
  errors.name = 'name is bad'
}

if(!verify(lastName)) {
  errors.lastName = 'last name is bad'
}

setError({ ...error, ...errors });
```

Comment: yep, how can i solve that?

Comment: answer updated with simplistic solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if(!verify(name)){
    setState(prevError => { 
       return {...prevError, name: 'name is bad'}
    });
}

if(!verify(lastName)){
    setState(prevError => { 
       return {...prevError, lastName: 'lastName is bad'}
    });
}
```

The value `error` wasn't updated after the first if block, due to asynchronous reasons. When you used the `error` value in the second if block, it still used it's orignal value.